# How open other tools like htop, vim by os's package

Tags: go

I'm writing a new project like a CLI with Go and I'm using the package [termui](https://github.com/gizak/termui), but in a time, I need that CLI open a file with editor like VIM without exit the current CLI, when close the VIM I can back to current CLI. Is it possible?

I've tried with this example below:

```golang
package main

import (
  "log"
  "os/exec"
)

func main() {
  // render the termui
  path := "SomeFile.bash"
  cmd := exec.Command("vim", path)

  err := cmd.Run()

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  } 
}
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but you need to assign os.Stdin, os.Stdout and os.Stderr to cmd's respective fields.

Comment: Do you have some links about this? I tried to find about, but I didn't anything :(

Comment: Do not put tags in the title--especially not twice

Comment: Okay, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did resolve with instance of `os` like `os.Stdin` or `os.Stdout`

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
  "log"
  "os/exec"
)

func main() {
  // render the termui
  path := "SomeFile.bash"
  cmd := exec.Command("vim", path)

  cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
  cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
  cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

  err := cmd.Run()

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  } 
}
```

Thanks @Peter by commentary :)